# Docker error: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn]: exit code: 1

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, nestjs

I recently cloned a repo from github which requires Docker to run.
The technologies that this project uses are Node, Express and NestJS.
I've tried `docker compose --env-file .env up` to start up docker but i'm getting the following error:

```
#0 17.97 [2/4] Fetching packages...
#0 167.4 info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/usr/src/api/yarn-error.log".
#0 167.4 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
#0 167.6 error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/@nestjs/common/-/common-8.2.0.tgz: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org".
#0 248.7 info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...

#0 691.3 info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn]: exit code: 1
```

Is there any way to fix this? (my main concern is the last error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker can't install npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215856/docker-cant-install-npm-packages)